# Getting MatchError when using a placeholder for an unused variable

Tags: scala, null, pattern-matching, unused-variables, scala-2.13

With Scala 2.13.x, I am getting `scala.MatchError: null` when I use a placeholder for an unused variable:

```
scala> object Test {
     |   val _: Any = null
     | }
object Test

scala> Test
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 41 elided
```

But with Scala 2.12.x, I am not getting `scala.MatchError: null`:

```
scala> object Test {
     |   val _: Any = null
     | }
defined object Test

scala> Test
res1: Test.type = Test$@784c5ef5
```

Any reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in [scala 2.13 release notes](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0):

> - Underscore is no longer a legal identifier unless backquoted (bug#10384)
>
>   - `val _ =` is now a pattern match (and discards the value without incurring a warning)
> - Make extractor patterns null safe. (#6485)
>
>   - `null` is treated as no match.

When combining both, we can see that this is not possible by design of Scala 2.13 . For more information you can read about at the pull requests at github implementing both features:

Underscore is no longer a legal identifier unless backquoted  - https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10384

Make extractor patterns null safe - https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6485